# Cannot alter tables after Django migration in posgres DB

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I really need to know why in the world we cannot change the column types after we do the migrations to `Postgres` DB.

I already created my models by `python manage.py makemigrations` then do `migrate`. Everything looks fine and tables are created on the postgres DB.

```
class test_API(models.Model):
    IDnumber = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
    State = models.CharField(max_length = 256, null = True)
    Exlcludmethod = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True)

class test_API_2(models.Model):
    Idnumber = models.Foreignkey(test_API, max_length = 256, blank=False, null = False)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=128, default="")
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Lets say we want to make change to IDnumber column from `Integerfield` to `Charfield`.

```
class test_API(models.Model):
        IDnumber = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False)
        State = models.CharField(max_length = 256, null = True)
        Exlcludmethod = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True)
```

and run the `python manage.py makemigrations` again

> return self.cursor.execute(sql)
> psycopg2.errors.DuplicateTable: relation "test_API" already exists

How can we modify/change column types and do migrations. What is the proper way of doing this ?

Using
Django:Django==4.0.3
Python = 3.9.1
Posgresql = 2.9.3

[Django migrations using RunPython to commit changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28429933/django-migrations-using-runpython-to-commit-changes)

[django 1.7 migrate gets error "table already exists"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25924858/django-1-7-migrate-gets-error-table-already-exists)

Comment: you aren't just changing it from an integer to a char, you're changing it from a relation to another table to no relation. If you add a `related_name` to the Idnumber field you might have some luck. What values do you expect to be stored in the new IDnumber field?

Comment: @AMG I expect to store Abcd type strings in `IDnumber` field.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want to drop the link to `test_API` in `test_API_2`. If you want to be able store 'abcd' type strings, and not try to keep anything from the relation previously created by the ForeignKey field, then I believe you need to do this in a two step process.

First step would be to remove (or comment) the IDNnumber field, make migrations, then add it back with a new type of field.

The IDNumber field was more than an integer field, it has an indexed relation to `test_API`, so you need to sever that first by removing the field, then create a new field with identical name.

Comment: thanks! wouldn't this remove the records in `IDnumber` ?

Comment: yes. That was what I was asking when I said "what values to you expect to be stored" in IDNumber. Previously it was a link to `test_api` but if you are switching to a CharField what specific values do you want to be stored instead? Which field would they come from? You may be interested in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64701570/4872140

Comment: Thanks for the link. That is the solution that I was looking for!  I think I'm going to store integers (1,2,3, ... ) or characters (a,bc,adssa...) so on in the charfield.