# Django migrations pending trigger event

Tags: python, django

I edited the my model field:

From:

```
principal_contact_info_designation = models.IntegerField()
```

To:

```
principal_contact_info_designation = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

and I make a migration then I run it, and it shows this:

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: cannot ALTER TABLE
>   "principal_contact_info" because it has pending trigger events

I am using python 3.5 and django 1.9.1

Comment: Please fix your formatting and show the full stack trace.

Comment: Have you read this? It's a short distance from your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12838111/south-cannot-alter-table-because-it-has-pending-trigger-events

Answer (score -1):

you need to add code for conversion previous values to new