# How can I change a null=True field to a null=False field if it already has null values in some places?

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: cannot ALTER TABLE "news_article" because it has pending trigger events
```

So, I have the following problem:

I have a Django class, Article, which contains several Char- and TextFields. They were set to `blank=True` AND `null=True` which is... unfortunate. Oh well, no I need to fix that. So after I deleted `null=True` and set `default=''`, I wrote the following thing into my migration:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models, migrations
import languagefields.utils
from languagefields.utils import LANGUAGES
from django.utils.translation import activate
from news.models import Article


def null_migrations(apps, schema_editor):
    activate('en')
    fields = ['short_title', 'description']
    for p in Article.objects.all():
        for l in LANGUAGES:
            for f in fields:
                if p.get_language(l, f) is None:
                    p.set_localized(l, f, '')
                    p.save()


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('news', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(null_migrations),
        migrations.AlterField(....
```

The fields are custom fields, based on the default Char-/TextFields, which enable translation. So there is a bunch of them. For every field you create there will be 5, a description in english, german and so on... So yeah, the little function works fine, I ran it on the server and cleaned the db entries manually, but that doesn't stop the exception above. So I thought I'd put it in the migration to clean out on the go. But still the exception. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance :)

EDIT

Split up the migrations in two:

`0002_null_cleaning.py`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models, migrations
import languagefields.utils
from languagefields.utils import LANGUAGES
from django.utils.translation import activate
from news.models import Article


def null_migrations(apps, schema_editor):
    activate('en')
    fields = ['short_title', 'description']
    for p in Article.objects.all():
        for l in LANGUAGES:
            for f in fields:
                if p.get_language(l, f) is None:
                    p.set_localized(l, f, '')
                    p.save()


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('news', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(null_migrations),
]
```

`0003_data_migration`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models, migrations
import languagefields.utils


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('news', '0002_null_cleaning'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(...
```

Still the same error, happening for `0003`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django-DB-Migrations: cannot ALTER TABLE because it has pending trigger events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12838111/django-db-migrations-cannot-alter-table-because-it-has-pending-trigger-events)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to split the migration into 2 actual migrations. They should happen in a transaction, so altering the data and altering the table is probably not kosher. Just create two migrations and it should work.

Comment: I tried to do that, split it up. I edited my post to show how I did it. It didn't change anything, do you know if I am doing something wrong there?