# Migration of Django field with default value 0 to PostgreSQL database

Tags: python, django

I want to update default column value but it seems like default value on columns is  is only on the ORM layer, and is not actually setting a default value in the DB and returns error django.db.utils.OperationalError: cannot ALTER TABLE "bps_registration_application" because it has pending trigger events.     Is it possible to  update default columnn value to 0 in postgress migrations by updating in django model?

This is models.py.

```
class Application(models.Model):
    registration_date = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    building_use = models.ForeignKey(to=system_settings.models.BuildingUse)
    building_category = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    building_structure_category = models.ForeignKey(to=system_settings.models.BuildingStructureCategory)
    building_length_ft = models.IntegerField(blank=True,  default=0)
    building_breadth_ft = models.IntegerField(blank=True,  default=0)
    building_height_ft = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0)
    building_length_in = models.IntegerField(blank=True,  default=0)
    building_breadth_in = models.IntegerField(blank=True,  default=0)
    building_height_in = models.IntegerField(blank=True,  default=0)

    building_storey = models.IntegerField(blank=True,  default=0)
    building_area = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)

    reg = models.ForeignKey(NewRegistration)
```

Comment: yes in django default value on columns is is only on the ORM, so you can add column with allow null and after id edit the migration and  add SQL to migration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django Migrations Add Field with Default as Function of Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29787853/django-migrations-add-field-with-default-as-function-of-model)

Comment: Can i update default value of existing  column without adding new column?

Comment: yes you can do it by alter table SET/DROP DEFAULT https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-altertable.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django-DB-Migrations: cannot ALTER TABLE because it has pending trigger events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12838111/django-db-migrations-cannot-alter-table-because-it-has-pending-trigger-events)